# Apache Spark - why does union order of withColumn DataFrame make different result of join?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Environment:

- OS: Windows 7
- Spark: version 2.1.0
- Scala: 2.11.8
- Java: 1.8

Spark Shell REPL

```
scala> val info = Seq((10, "A"), (100, "B")).toDF("id", "type")
info: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, type: string]

scala> val statC = Seq((1)).toDF("sid").withColumn("stype", lit("A"))
statC: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [sid: int, stype: string]

scala> val statD  = Seq((2)).toDF("sid").withColumn("stype", lit("B"))
statD: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [sid: int, stype: string]

scala> info.join(statC.union(statD), $"id"/10 === $"sid" and $"type"===$"stype").show
+---+----+---+-----+
| id|type|sid|stype|
+---+----+---+-----+
| 10|   A|  1|    A|
+---+----+---+-----+

scala> info.join(statD.union(statC), $"id"/10 === $"sid" and $"type"===$"stype").show
+---+----+---+-----+
| id|type|sid|stype|
+---+----+---+-----+
+---+----+---+-----+
```

`statC` and `statD` generate column `stype` by `WithColumn`, the REPL above show that 
`statC.union(statD)` and `statD.union(statC)` make the join result different.

I explain the Physical Plain of the two join

```
scala> info.join(statC.union(statD), $"id"/10 === $"sid" and $"type"===$"stype").explain
== Physical Plan ==
*BroadcastHashJoin [(cast(id#342 as double) / 10.0)], [cast(sid#420 as double)], Inner, BuildRight
:- *Project [_1#339 AS id#342, _2#340 AS type#343]
:  +- *Filter ((isnotnull(_2#340) && ((A <=> _2#340) || (B <=> _2#340))) && (_2#340 = A))
:     +- LocalTableScan [_1#339, _2#340]
+- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(cast(input[0, int, false] as double)))
   +- Union
      :- LocalTableScan [sid#420, stype#423]
      +- LocalTableScan [sid#430, stype#433]

scala> info.join(statD.union(statC), $"id"/10 === $"sid" and $"type"===$"stype").explain
== Physical Plan ==
*BroadcastHashJoin [(cast(id#342 as double) / 10.0)], [cast(sid#430 as double)], Inner, BuildRight
:- *Project [_1#339 AS id#342, _2#340 AS type#343]
:  +- *Filter ((isnotnull(_2#340) && ((B <=> _2#340) || (A <=> _2#340))) && (_2#340 = B))
:     +- LocalTableScan [_1#339, _2#340]
+- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(cast(input[0, int, false] as double)))
   +- Union
      :- LocalTableScan [sid#430, stype#433]
      +- LocalTableScan [sid#420, stype#423]
```

the explain result show that, the union order of `statC` and `statD` make the `Filter` condition in `BroadcastHashJoin` different:

when `statC.union(statD)`, the filter condition is:

```
Filter ((isnotnull(_2#340) && ((A <=> _2#340) || (B <=> _2#340))) && (_2#340 = A))
```

when `statD.union(statC)`, the filter condition is:

```
Filter ((isnotnull(_2#340) && ((B <=> _2#340) || (A <=> _2#340))) && (_2#340 = B))
```

But when the two unioned DataFrame are generated without withColumn, the union order has no effect on join result.

```
scala> val info = Seq((10, "A"), (100, "B")).toDF("id", "type")
info: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, type: string]

scala> val statA = Seq((1, "A")).toDF("sid", "stype")
statA: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [sid: int, stype: string]

scala> val statB = Seq((2, "B")).toDF("sid", "stype")
statB: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [sid: int, stype: string]

scala> info.join(statA.union(statB), $"id"/10 === $"sid" and $"type"===$"stype").show
+---+----+---+-----+
| id|type|sid|stype|
+---+----+---+-----+
| 10|   A|  1|    A|
+---+----+---+-----+

scala> info.join(statB.union(statA), $"id"/10 === $"sid" and $"type"===$"stype").show
+---+----+---+-----+
| id|type|sid|stype|
+---+----+---+-----+
| 10|   A|  1|    A|
+---+----+---+-----+

scala> info.join(statA.union(statB), $"id"/10 === $"sid" and $"type"===$"stype").explain
== Physical Plan ==
*BroadcastHashJoin [(cast(id#342 as double) / 10.0), type#343], [cast(sid#352 as double), stype#353], Inner, BuildRight
:- *Project [_1#339 AS id#342, _2#340 AS type#343]
:  +- *Filter isnotnull(_2#340)
:     +- LocalTableScan [_1#339, _2#340]
+- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(cast(input[0, int, false] as double), input[1, string, true]))
   +- Union
      :- *Project [_1#349 AS sid#352, _2#350 AS stype#353]
      :  +- *Filter isnotnull(_2#350)
      :     +- LocalTableScan [_1#349, _2#350]
      +- *Project [_1#359 AS sid#362, _2#360 AS stype#363]
         +- *Filter isnotnull(_2#360)
            +- LocalTableScan [_1#359, _2#360]

scala> info.join(statB.union(statA), $"id"/10 === $"sid" and $"type"===$"stype").explain
== Physical Plan ==
*BroadcastHashJoin [(cast(id#342 as double) / 10.0), type#343], [cast(sid#362 as double), stype#363], Inner, BuildRight
:- *Project [_1#339 AS id#342, _2#340 AS type#343]
:  +- *Filter isnotnull(_2#340)
:     +- LocalTableScan [_1#339, _2#340]
+- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(cast(input[0, int, false] as double), input[1, string, true]))
   +- Union
      :- *Project [_1#359 AS sid#362, _2#360 AS stype#363]
      :  +- *Filter isnotnull(_2#360)
      :     +- LocalTableScan [_1#359, _2#360]
      +- *Project [_1#349 AS sid#352, _2#350 AS stype#353]
         +- *Filter isnotnull(_2#350)
            +- LocalTableScan [_1#349, _2#350]
```

the explain show that in statA/statB, `id/type` and `sid/stype` are all included in BroadcastHashJoin, but in statC/statD, only `id` and `sid` are included in BroadcastHashJoin.

Why does join has different semantics when the order of union is changed on the DataFrame which are generated by withColumn?

Comment: This is surely a bug. I can confirm that the error is fully reproducable in version 2.1.0, but it is _not_ present i 2.0.0. I think you should file a bug report.

Comment: thanks @GlennieHellesSindholt , I find a bug report in spark issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19954, may be it will be fixed in 2.1.x